# How do I get the selected file's filesystem path using ResourceNavigator in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, path, rcp, navigator

This is what I tried, but it failed.And it alerted that 'org.eclipse .core .internal.File cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resource.IProject'.

```
public void runDefaultAction(IStructuredSelection selection) {
    Object element = selection.getFirstElement();
    if (element instanceof IFile) {
        openFileAction.selectionChanged(selection);
        openFileAction.run();
        String selectedPathString = ((IFile) element).getFullPath().toString();
        System.out.println(selectedPathString);
        //get project absolute path
        ISelectionService service = navigator.getSite().getWorkbenchWindow()
                .getSelectionService();
        IStructuredSelection selection1 = (IStructuredSelection) service
                .getSelection("BIT_DEC.myNavigator");
        IProject iproject = (IProject) selection1.getFirstElement();
        String real_file_path = iproject.getLocation().toString();
        System.out.println(real_file_path);
        .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **it alerted that 'org.eclipse .core .internal.File cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resource.IProject'.**

Because:

[image]

Corrected last 3 lines of your code.

```java
if(selection1.getFirstElement() instanceof IFile) {
  IFile file = (IFile) selection1.getFirstElement();
  String real_file_path = file.getLocation().toString();
  System.out.println(real_file_path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IFile` has a `getLocation()` method that gives you the full path directly.

Note: The selection returned by the selection service will generally be the same as the selection you are given. You can get the project from an `IFile` by calling its `getProject()` method.